# ntpd.pid not getting generated even when ntpd is running in centos7

Tags: centos, ntp, ntpd

I have recently upgraded to centos7. I could observe that ntpd.pid is not generated when the ntpd service is started.

Earlier, in centos 6, when we start the ntpd service the file ntpd.pid is automatically generated and when we stop the service the file will be deleted from /var/run.

I couldn't find any sources of changes, appreciate if someone can point any os level changes.

I tried disabling chronyd service but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

NTP version that I was using with centos7 was ntp-4.2.6p5-28.el7.centos.x86_64 where the /etc/sysconfig/ntpd options has been modified from OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g" to OPTIONS="-g".

The -p option is path to the PID file.